# Language is not changing when installed through app package in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, culture

I am developing an application and have create two resources for arabic and english. The problem we are facing is, when I install the app with the device connected to visual studio and launch the application, and change language of the application, it works fine and changes the language.

But when I am creating the application package and install the application with the package, it does not change the language with the same code that is working when installed through visual studio.

Any idea why that might be happening? that's how i am changing the culture.

```
  public void ChangeEnglishToArabicCulture() {

        var culture = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
        Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
        (Window.Current.Content as Frame).FlowDirection = Windows.UI.Xaml.FlowDirection.RightToLeft;

    }

    public void ChangeArabicToEnglishCulture() {
        var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
        (Window.Current.Content as Frame).FlowDirection = Windows.UI.Xaml.FlowDirection.LeftToRight;

    }
```

Comment: Maybe the language resources are not installed when you deploy from package (appxbundle). In this case only [resources needed are installed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464929.aspx). Try to open [Settings on phone, open languages tab, check if both languages are added](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh967761(v=win.10).aspx), then install your app.

Comment: but how do i solve it? :/

Comment: how is it working when installing from Visual studio if it's settings problem? i think the problem is with deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had the same issues.

When debugging my code I could change the application language without any issues. However, applications deployed would only work with the default language.

This turned out to be a deployment issue.

Generate an `APPX` file, rather than an `APPXBUNDLE` file, and deploy that (using `Add-AppxPackage`).